# CORS error after adding custom client service to Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I've followed the [Identity Server 4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/) docs and created a working test instance locally. I've then added an example Javascript client following [this tutorial](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html#). This all works fine whilst still using the test users and clients.

I now want to start breaking out the test data into production-ready services. I thought I'd start with my clients. Here is the Identity Server setup code from the `ConfigureServices` method in my `Startup`:

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
    //.AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
    .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());

builder.Services.AddTransient<IdentityServer4.Stores.IClientStore, CustomClientStore>();
```

Literally the only thing I've changed here is commenting out the `AddInMemoryClients` line and adding the last line which registers a new client store. Right now all this `CustomClientStore` class does is replicate the `Config.GetClients()` test data.

However, when I now run my demo Javascript app and click my Login button, I now get the following Javascript error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://localhost:54458/.well-known/openid-configuration. (Reason: CORS
>   header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

http://localhost:54458 is my IS4 instance obviously. I haven't touched my CORS configuration, and if I comment out the `AddTransient` line above and restore the `AddInMemoryClients` line everything works again.

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? The exception middleware **clears/removes** (when an exception is thrown) any CORS header set by the middleware before

Comment: No exceptions, no. But I've now answered my own question. See below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my answer by poking inside Identity Server's own code. It turns out that when registering the test client store using the `AddInMemoryClients` extension, Identity Server is also implementing a CORS policy at the same time. You can see [this code here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/50a5216fe001ca189d2615e3a1662dc7d965f9ab/src/IdentityServer4/Configuration/DependencyInjection/BuilderExtensions/InMemory.cs).

This CORS policy uses another in-memory implementation, this time of `ICorsPolicyService`. This implementation takes the `AllowedCorsOrigins` properties of the configured clients to determine if a requesting origin is allowed.

So my solution was to create this extension method...

```
public static IIdentityServerBuilder AddCustomCorsPolicy(this IIdentityServerBuilder builder)
{
    var existingCors = builder.Services.Where(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(ICorsPolicyService)).LastOrDefault();
    if (existingCors != null &&
        existingCors.ImplementationType == typeof(DefaultCorsPolicyService) &&
        existingCors.Lifetime == ServiceLifetime.Transient)
    {
        builder.Services.AddTransient<ICorsPolicyService, CustomCorsPolicyService>();
    }

    return builder;
}
```

...then implement `CustomCorsPolicyService` to check the requesting origin against those setup in my client base, then add `AddCustomCorsPolicy` to my Identity Server setup.

Comment: You can simply inject services.AddTransient<ICorsPolicyService, CustomCorsPolicyService>(); without creating extension method

Answer (score 1):

In your Javascript request you need to set the following field:

```
request.credentials
```

See [here for the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials), you probably want `same-origin`, but if it is going to be a fully internal infrastructure then it ok to use `include'. An example:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

return fetch(`${API_PATH}${SIGN_IN_PATH}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials: 'include',
  headers: ...,
  body: ...
});
```

In your `Configure` method of `Startup.cs` you will also need to enable CORS using:

```
app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

You can build your own `CorsOptions` instance and pass this in if `AllowAll` is not suitable. More reference docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, but you'll see from my OP that the problem was directly in how I was configuring Identity Server, not my Javascript client. I've now answered my own question below...